# mongodb documents values in treeview in python

Tags: python, mongodb, list, tkinter, treeview

**I want to display mongodb documents values in treeview in python.
Below is my code, but it not displays data in proper manner in treeview.**

```
collection = myDB['students']
rows = list(collection.find())

if len(rows)!=0:
   self.student_table.delete(*self.student_table.get_children())
   for row in rows:
      self.student_table.insert("",END,values=row.values())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `row.values()` (type `dict_values`) to `list`:

```py
for row in rows:
   self.student_table.insert("", END, values=list(row.values()))
```

Comment: @ShamsherSingh If it solves your issue, consider to accept it as the answer.